# How to avoid adding duplicate values in shared preferences in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In android, i am adding string values using shared preferences, but i want to compare the value which i am going to add to shared preferences with values which are already stored in shared preferences to avoid adding duplicate values, but i am not getting how to do this?
or is there any alternate method to avoid adding duplicate values in shared preferences?

I am adding string values using following code

```
  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
  editor.putString(Name, s);
  editor.commit();
```

Comment: Have try anything ?? if any then please paste code ..

Answer (score 4):

In android you cannot really have duplicate value in sharedPreference because every time you change or modify a value on sharedPreference it will replace the previous with the current. So since every instance of it has a single unique key, which mean it will always be unique (in my experience every time i messed up with this keys like giving the same name key for both an Int and boolean for example i end up crashing the app or having some kind of exception)

If im wrong i hope someone else will correct me and provide you with a better answer!

Comment: so then we can not store more then one values in sharedPreference?

Comment: You can add more than on Value of course but with different "KEY" name
or if the key is the same you will just overwrite the previous one!

Answer (score 3):

First get String value from SharedPreferences as `oldvalue` then compare with `newvalue` which you want to store. If String not match then save `newvalue` in SharedPreferences.

Try something like this

```
String str_newvalue = "new string here"; 
SharedPreferences sharedpref = this.getSharedPreferences(this.getPackageName(), context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String str_oldvalue = sharedpref.getString("key", "");

if (!str_newvalue.equals(str_oldvalue)) {
    sharedpref.edit().putString("key", str_newvalue).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it,does this compare with every values or only with previous value?

Comment: @AnandK: If you want to store more than one value then store it with different `key_values` then retrieve string with related key..

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether I'm understanding your question quite well or not, but Android's `SharedPreferences`has it's own [contains](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) to check if a a key already exists or not.

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedpreferences.contains(NAME)) //It already contains NAME key
```

On the other hand, if your worries are about a single key's value not to be repeated, just read it before storing the new value and compare themselves, no more.

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!sharedpreferences.getString(NAME, "").equals(s)) { 
    // It does not have the same value, store 's'
    sharedpreferences
       .edit();
       .putString(NAME, s);
       .commit();
}
```

However, in this particular case I wouldn't perform this verification, just overwrite the value and that's it, as it always gonna be the same.

Comment: thank you,can we store more then one value in SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes sure, just use different keys for those values and that's it. In your example you have `Name`as value. Using a single key, you may use [SharedPreferences.Editor's putStringSet] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>))

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if(restoredText.matches(your string))
{
// do nothing
}
 else
 {
 //save your data
 }
 }
```